# SQL server 2008 r2 How does TOP works?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

How actually TOP works ?

I have gone through [TOP(Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189463%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). I understand that TOP is used to limit result set.
But what I have not understood is let say I specified `Select Top(10) from Table where some condition` does it stop after processing first 10 records from the table which may contain only 5 records which match the condition or it will process all the records first and then return first 10 record of result set.

Comment: Also note: without a `ORDER BY` clause, a `TOP (x)` really doesn't make any sense. If you want the *first 10 rows* - you always need to define how these rows are *ordered* (by what column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the second assumption is one which is correct.

> First it will process all the records and then return first 10 record of result set.

Database engine would run the query ignoring the the **TOP** clause, and then at the end just shrink that result set down to the **n** number of rows that was requested.

Comment: Does it work similarly if you have join in query or it changes behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer exists in this [thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24832/how-and-why-does-top-impact-an-execution-plan). Actually, SQL Server 2008 uses  different model to execute queries.